# Laravel 5. How to iterate through Eloquent properties

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have the following function in Controller:

```
public function getProduct()
{
return Product::join('shopping_list_items', 'products.id', '=', 'shopping_list_items.product_id' )
->join('shop_lists', 'shop_lists.id', '=', 'shopping_list_items.shopping_list_id')
->select('products.product_name', 'products.id')
->where('shop_lists.id', $this->id);
}
```

This code in the view works perfectly and shows product name:

```
{{$shoppinglists->getProduct()->first()->product_name}}
```

But I can't loop through it like this:

```
@foreach($shoppinglists->getProduct() as $sh)
{{$sh->product_name}}<br>
@endforeach
```

Though it doesn't show any error.

Comment: after the where, add ->get();

Comment: Thank you! Could you please explain difference of objects with and without get()?

Comment: The difference is that without it, it's not a thing. ->get(); tells it to execute the query and return the object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `getProduct()` method returns an instance of the Database Builder, not the collection, that is why you can do `->first()`, which basically does a fetch limit 1 and gets you the object.

So, you need to call the `->get()` or maybe `paginate()` to actually do a fetch of the data to the database and obtain the collection of objects.

So, bottom line, just do:

```
@foreach($shoppinglists->getProduct()->get() as $sh)
    {{$sh->product_name}}<br>
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 1):

As @Carlos explained, you need to use `get()` to get values from database.

```
public function getProduct()
{
return Product::join('shopping_list_items', 'products.id', '=', 'shopping_list_items.product_id' )

->join('shop_lists', 'shop_lists.id', '=', 'shopping_list_items.shopping_list_id')

->select('products.product_name', 'products.id')

->where('shop_lists.id', $this->id)
->get();
}
```

This will return you a JSON object. If you need an array output from this query, use `pluck('filed name');` instead of `get();`
In your view, use

```
@foreach($shoppinglists as $sh)
{{$sh->product_name}}<br>
@endforeach
```